# All functions such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_n^{n+\frac 1n} f(x)dx$ is a non-zero finite value

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I’m interested in finding all functions $f(x)$ (if any), such that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_n^{n+\frac 1n} f(x)dx$$ is a finite non-zero value.

Let’s try evaluating this limit for a few functions that one would expect to follow this property. All I could deduce was that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f’(x) \ne 0$ otherwise our limit would be zero.

$$\int_n^{n+\frac 1n} x^2 \ dx = \frac13 \left[ \left(n + \frac 1n \right)^3 - n^3\right] \\ = \frac{3n^2 + 3+ \frac{1}{n^2}}{3n}$$
It’s easy to see that the limit of this diverges to $\infty$.

$$\int_n^{n+\frac 1n} \sqrt x \ dx = \frac 23 \cdot \frac{3n + \frac 3n + \frac{1}{n^3}}{\left(n + \frac 1n \right)^{\frac 32} + n^{\frac 32} } $$

This time, the limit goes to $0$. So, there must be one (or more than one?) value of $k$ with $\frac 12 \lt k \lt 2$ such that $f(x)=x^k$ satisfies our property. I saw that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_n^{n+\frac 1n} x \ dx = 1$

Are there other such functions? Can this be generalized?

Comment: You could have 'spiky triangle' functions that are zero except for on $\bigcup (n,n+1/n)$ and integrate to some constant there.

Comment: @Integrand But $n$ varies over the reals. Wouldn’t $\bigcup (n,n+ \frac 1n)  = \mathbb R$ ?

Comment: Hmm, I guess I defaulted to having $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Would you be amenable to an edit changing the limits to $x,x+1/x$ and the dummy variable to $t$?

Comment: @Integrand I don’t think that’s a good idea, as someone has already posted an answer using $n$. Besides, writing $f(x)$ instead of $f(t)$ looks much more standard to me, at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we assume that $f$ is continuous we have, by the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals), that $$\int_{n}^{n+1/n}f\left(x\right)dx=\frac{f\left(c_{n}\right)}{n}$$ where $c_{n}\in\left[n,n+1/n\right]$. Hence $$\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f\left(c_{n}\right)}{n}=\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{f\left(n\right)}{n}$$ and this limit is finite if and only if $f\left(x\right)\sim ax,\,a\in\mathbb{R}$, as $x\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: You've assumed that $c_n=n,$ but this is not necessarily true.

Comment: @Allawonder I say that $c_{n}$ grows as $n$, by comparison.

Comment: How do you know?

Comment: @Allawonder $n\leq c_{n}\leq n+\frac{1}{n}$ hence $1\leq\frac{c_{n}}{n}\leq1+\frac{1}{n^{2}}$. Now take $n\rightarrow+\infty$.

Comment: Oh, great. Actually the inequalities are strict, but then your claim is still true. +1

Comment: Using the same approach, one can also conclude that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_n^{n+\frac{1}{n^k}} f(x)dx$$ will be non-zero and finite iff $f(x) \sim ax^k$ for $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

We want to consider the integral $$I=\int\limits ^{n+1/n}_{n} f( x) dx$$
Where $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.
Suppose $f$ has antiderivative $F$. Then $$I=F(n+\frac{1}{n})-F(n)$$
Using a first order Taylor approximation, $$F\left( n+\frac{1}{n}\right) \approx F( n) +F'( n)\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
And since $F'=f$, $$I \approx \frac{f(n)}{n}$$
And this approximation will clearly get better and better for larger and larger $n$. Therefore for $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{f( n)}{n}$ to be finite and nonzero, $\text{deg}(f)=1$. So linear equations are the only types of equations that have this property. 
EDIT: functions with linear-like growth will also have this property. So functions such as $\frac{x}{\log(x)}$, $x+e^{-x}$, and so on.

Comment: The only functions with primitives. You have not considered functions without primitive.

Comment: @Allawonder $f$ need not have an analytic antiderivative as we are only considering definite integrals. Notice I was able to remove mention of $F$ in my expression for $I$.

Comment: Clearly you have only shown that this is the case only for integrands with primitives.

Comment: In other words, without that supposition your proof couldn't have flown.

Comment: @Allawonder Assuming $f$ is a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then $F$ is as well. Even if $F$ is not closed form, $F(n+1/n)$ and $F(n)$ still exist.

Comment: I don't think you understand me. Clearly you think all functions have primitives. This, however, is not the case.

Comment: @Allawonder Every continuous function has a primitive. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative

Comment: Of course. But why must we assume continuity? All we need for a function to be integrable is that it be bounded and not oscillate too quickly.

Comment: @Allawonder Fair enough. I'm not sure how I'd extend this proof to non-integrable functions.

Comment: You mean integrable functions without primitives?

Comment: @Allawonder Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial each term is like $ax^m$. The definite integral is

$\frac{a}{m+1}(n+\frac{1}{n})^{m+1}-\frac{a}{m+1}n^{m+1}$

$=\frac{a}{m+1}(n^{m+1}+(m+1)n^m(\frac{1}{n})^{1}+\frac{(m+1)m}{2}n^{m-1}(\frac{1}{n})^{2}+ ...-n^{m+1})$

$=\frac{a}{m+1}((m+1)n^m(\frac{1}{n})^{1}+\frac{(m+1)m}{2}n^{m-1}(\frac{1}{n})^{2}+ ...)$

$=an^m(\frac{1}{n})+a\frac{m}{2}n^{m-1}(\frac{1}{n})^{2}+ ...)$

$=an^{m-1}+a\frac{m}{2}n^{m-3}+ ...$

If $m>1$ the first term becomes infinite as $n\to\infty$. If $m<1$ the first term (and later terms) approach zero as $n\to\infty$. If $m=1$ then the first term is $an^0=a$ and later terms approach zero. So the only polynomial function is $f(x)=ax$

Comment: Interesting. That accounts for all polynomials. I wonder if non-polynomial functions can be solutions...

Comment: For some (fairly) easy generalisation, we could add any other function whose integral over the range approaches 0 as n→∞. I suspect we could multiply by a function such as $1-1/n$ which converges to a fixed limit. Nothing else comes to mind, especially if n is real instead of positive integer.